# angular data binding returning key instead of value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angular-template

I am working with managed fields from a webserver that look like this:

```
{
   "fields":{
      "relationshipStatus":[
         {
            "fieldId":4,
            "name":"Committed"
         },
         {
            "fieldId":2,
            "name":"Dating"
         },
         {
            "fieldId":6,
            "name":"Engaged"
         },
         {
            "fieldId":3,
            "name":"Exclusive"
         },
         {
            "fieldId":7,
            "name":"Married"
         },
         {
            "fieldId":8,
            "name":"Open Relationship"
         },
         {
            "fieldId":5,
            "name":"Partnered"
         },
         {
            "fieldId":1,
            "name":"Single"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I have a drop down selector that will allow me to filter profiles by the field name doing this:

```
<select ng-model='$storage.filter.relationshipStatus' 
  ng-options="option.fieldId as option.name for option in managedFields.relationshipStatus" 
  ng-change="changeFilter('relationshipStatus')">
  <option value="">Any Relationship Status</option>
```

In another template where I view profiles, when I try to get the relationship status by using `{{profile.relationshipStatus}}`, say if they filled out their profile as Committed, it returns the number 4.  I understand that correlates to Committed, but I am unsure how to get the profile template for an individual profile to display committed, instead of 4.  I've also tried using `{{profile.relationshipStatus.value}}` I'm pretty new to this, so I'm not sure if I can even adjust this to pull the strings instead of the numbers?, or am I going to have to write some javascript to process by the numbers and output the actual strings, ex. `{{profile.relationshipStatus | relationshipToString}}`  I've tried looking up data binding on multiple examples, but I'm not sure I'm finding any examples that apply as I'm pretty new yet.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?  Thank You

Comment: No exactly clear about your ask but are you trying to bind select like this https://plnkr.co/edit/FZx15s5tOYh8esyhVp74?p=preview

Comment: I'm trying to display the name, instead of the fieldId.  I can pull profile information using {{profile.age}} for the age, but when I do it for things like the relationship, when I use {{profile.relationshipStatus}} it will show 1 for single, 2 for dating, etc.  I can't figure out how to make the template display the actual names, as in Single, Dating, Married.

Comment: whats is this profile object? could you past this object in your question

Answer (score 0):

I think below line is wrong, you are trying to pick fieldId and pretending it as option.name

```
ng-options="option.fieldId as option.name for option in managedFields.relationshipStatus"

//try this
ng-options="option.name as option.name for option in managedFields.relationshipStatus"
```

see details
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: I was using that as an example to show that I can get the actual names to show in the drop down list, used for a filter, and that does work, instead of showing 1, 2, 3.  the problem I have is when I pull the data for one profile, it shows the numbers, instead of single, dating, etc, and the user only selects one setting out fo 7 for the profiles relationship status.

Comment: I'm trying to display the relationship status in a table on a template so I'm using <td>{{profile.relationshipStatus}}</td> which shows me a number instead of the equivalent string.  I guess what I'm trying to figure out, can you pull one field in a table, and have the string display, similar to how "option.fieldId as option.name" shows the actual strings, by using the curly brackets, or is there another way to pull that data?  The user can change that at any time, so I would like to display what they have it set to, not 1, or 2, or 3, or 4, but as single, dating, etc.